# SSAS cube in Excel, unnecessary dimension is showing

Tags: excel, ssas, cube

we are having problem with our cube in excel,

for one measure group, unnecessary dimension is showing without any direct relation in the cube. meaning there is no key connect between these two tables.

anyone has any idea why this is happening?

thanks

Comment: There is no relation between this dimension and measure group on 'Dimension Usage' tab of the cube, but some other measure groups are connected to this dimension, is it?

Comment: Alex, that is correct

Comment: Well, it's regular behavior AFAIK. No way to hide unlinked items, except using perspectives: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3213/sql-server-analysis-services-perspectives/